# Adding Firebase Framework to iOS Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, linker-errors

I am trying to add Firebase Messaging to my iOS Project. I can't use Pods because something with them is broken on my Developermachine. So I am adding the Framework manually. As mentioned by the Readme I added all Frameworks of the Analytics and Messaging Folders along with the Firebase.h to my Xcode Project. I added Storekit.framework, libz, libc++ and libsqlite3.0 as mentioned on other Stackoverflow Questions to get rid of the most linker errors. But still I can't compile/link my project because of the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAInAppPurchaseTransactionReporter_ca1fe3eb82b823d5f96d3f8b4baedc9c.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAProductsRequest_8f770071350872416d311668917f3a41.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't get why they are missing or which library I need to add to make this run. Does someone know what to do ?

And I should also mention that I am using Qt on this project.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.

I don't know why this framework is required, but i added StoreKit.framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries which made it compile.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try go to the entry header file of your project then add

```
#import "Firebase.h"
```

to see if problem is solved.

Comment: To anyone who is integrating firebase without Cocoapods AND forced to use 6.11.0 due to project limitation which only can runs on Xcode10.x at the moment, THIS IS THE SOLUTION! THANKS SNOY